# Member Object That Cannot Be Instantiated Upon Declaration

Tags: c++, object, opengl, instantiation

Here is a *Mesh* class:

```
// Mesh.h

class Mesh
{
   std::array<float, 144> m_CanvasVertices;
   std::array<unsigned short, 36> m_CanvasIndices;
   std::array<float, 24>  m_SquareVertices;
   std::array<unsigned short, 6> m_SquareIndices;
   std::array<glm::vec2, 32> m_SquareOffsets;
   Buffers::VertexBuffer* Canvas_VBO;
public:
   Mesh();
   void InitialiseMembers();
};

// Mesh.cpp:

Mesh::Mesh()
: m_CanvasVertices(), m_CanvasIndices(), m_SquareVertices(),
  m_SquareIndices(), m_SquareOffsets(), Canvas_VBO()
{
    InitialiseMembers();

    Buffers::VertexBuffer aVBO(m_CanvasVertices);
    Canvas_VBO = &aVBO;
}

void Mesh::InitialiseMembers()
{
    m_CanvasVertices = { ... }; 
    m_CanvasIndices = { ... };
    m_SquareVertices = { ... };
    m_SquareIndices = { ... };
    m_SquareOffsets = { ... };
}
```

Here is a *VertexBuffer* class:

```
class VertexBuffer
{
    unsigned int m_VBO;
public:
    template<typename T, unsigned short int N>
    VertexBuffer(const std::array<T, N>& data, int draw_method = GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        : m_VBO(0)
    {
        GLFunctionCall(glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO));
        GLFunctionCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO));
        if (draw_method == GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        {
            GLFunctionCall(glNamedBufferData(m_VBO, sizeof(data), &data, draw_method));
        }
        else if (draw_method == GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
        {
            GLFunctionCall(glNamedBufferData(m_VBO, sizeof(data), &data, draw_method));
        }
    }

    template<typename T, unsigned short int N>
    void UpdateDynamicData(std::array<T, N>& data) const
    {
        GLFunctionCall(glNamedBufferData(m_VBO, sizeof(data), &data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW));
    }

    ~VertexBuffer();
    void Bind() const;
    void Unbind() const;
    unsigned int GetBufferID() const;
};
```

I want to create a *VertexBuffer* object inside my *Mesh* class. The *Mesh* member *Canvas_VBO* is a *VertexBuffer* object, are therefore cannot instantiated upon deceleration (by this I simply mean that I cannot instantiate the object in the class fields). For example, if I wanted to create the object inside main.cpp, I could do it like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<float, 144> canvas_vertices = { ... };

    Buffers::VertexBuffer Canvas_VBO(canvas_vertices);
    // ^ buffer generated, 'canvas_vertices' inputted to buffer data, etc...
}
```

But because *Canvas_VBO* is a class member, I cannot instantiate object in this way.

In the *Mesh* constructor, I found a workaround where I create a temporary object ('aVBO')  and then set the memory address of the member *Canvas_VBO* to this newly created temporary object. This seems to work fine but I have a niggling feeling that this may not be good practice, so looking for some advice on this, i.e. is this bad practice? Are there any other workarounds? etc, etc..

Comment: It's straight up undefined behavior. After the constructor is over, `aVBO` dies and your `Canvas_VBO` pointer points to a deleted object. `new`/`delete` can help, but just store a `std::unique_ptr<Buffer::VertexBuffer>` instead.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `Canvas_VBO` must be a pointer though? I don't see any reason in your code why it can't be a plain member like the others...

Comment: @Max Langhof Nope, I made it a pointer because it was convenient to transfer the memory address from the temporary object this way, but as you have pointed out, the memory will be freed when the temporary object goes out of scope so this method is useless.

Comment: You can add a move ctor and move assignment operator to `VertexBuffer`  so it can deal with moving itself in an efficient way (if it's even needed). Perhaps you should show what the `VertexBuffer` looks like?

Comment: The problem with making it a normal member (non-pointer) is that I don't see any way in which I can call the *VertexBuffer* constructor on the object, seeing as though *m_CanvasVertices* needs to be passed as an argument.

Comment: @RyanWalter Just use the member initializer list. You already have one, you can initialize (i.e. call constructors for) your member objects in there!

Comment: @MaxLanghof I can't use the member initialiser list because I need to pass *m_CanvasVertices* to the constructor. The array *m_CanvasVertices* has to be filled outside of the *Mesh* initialiser list (since it is an std::array).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've updated the question now to show the *VertexBuffer* class.

Comment: @RyanWalter I see. In that case, `std::unique_ptr` would be the tool of choice.

Comment: @MaxLanghof but I don't see how using a smart pointer enables me to call the ```VertexBuffer``` constructor from the body of the ```Mesh``` constructor?

Comment: @RyanWalter Try writing the code using `new` and `delete` for managing `Canvas_VBO`. Assuming you understand how those work, it should be clear why this allows you to call the `VertexBuffer` constructor where you need it. Then, `unique_ptr` does the same thing just abstracted in a way that prevents most of the problems (as in "programmer mistakes") that come with raw `new` and `delete` and should thus be used instead.

Comment: I don't think `new` and `delete` will help here since the same problem will occur where the memory is freed once the object goes out of scope. I don't see any way in which I can call the `VertexBuffer` constructor outside of the `Mesh` initialiser list, and I can't call it from the initialiser list for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: Manage to solve it by declaring `Canvas_VBO` in the `Mesh` class field like so: `std::unique_ptr<Buffers::VertexBuffer> Canvas_VBO;`, and then calling 'make_unique' inside the body of the `Mesh` constructor to access the `VertexBuffer` constructor: `Canvas_VBO = std::make_unique<Buffers::VertexBuffer>(m_CanvasVertices);`. Got there in the end - thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the (stack) address of `aVBO` won't work because the object is freed after the constructor ends.

Make `Canvas_VBO` a `std::unique_ptr<Buffers::VertexBuffer>` and in the constructor allocate it dynamically with `std::make_unique<Buffers::VertexBuffer>(m_CanvasVertices)`.

For modern C++ memory management read up on smart pointers.

Comment: FYI: Use single backticks (`\``) to format inline code snippets.